# Ethernet network: Accteptance and discarding of messages based on their destniation addresses

Tags: ethernet

In Ethernet networks, the MAC layer is the first layer to detect the destination address of the received message.

my questions: is that means that the transceiver shall take a copy of each message on the bus and forward it to the MAC layer who will decide to accept that message or discard it? If so, this means that the MAC layer must have a very large buffers to save all that intended and non intended message. am I correct ?

Answer (score 0):

The MAC layer does not typically have much buffering. It may not even be able to store a full packet. Packets instead stream through the MAC.

Packets enter and exit the MAC one flit at a time. It may take hundreds of cycles for a full packet to pass into a MAC depending on the size of the packet and the width of the interface. For example, a MAC with an 8-byte interface (8-byte flit size) will take 1000 cycles to receive an 8kB packet.

The MAC may only have 800 bytes of buffering. In that case, the packet will start coming out the other end after 100 cycles when only 10% of the packet has entered. In fact, many MACs have a latency well below 100 cycles.

Packets which are rejected on the basis of destination address stream in one side but nothing comes out the other side. The frames are simply forgotten/dropped as they arrive.